# Getting blob links from headers using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, blob, request-headers

I'm scraping a website that streams free movies using requests & BeautifulSoup, and I was able to get the streaming page. But I need to get the video source so I can stream/download the video and I'm stuck here.

The video source is  `"src = blob:https://example.com/blabla....etc "` , and it's not the original source.

After googling blob sources, I found out that the original video source will be in the header itself:

[image: photo]

(you need to go to  Network > find the stream.m3u8 > copy the header

How can we do this with Python code? Getting that link?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: i just wanted to show how to get the link , the text itself is not important :)

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the M3U8 file, you can parse the response using regex.

```
#enter code here
import requests
import re
url = 'https://www.someexamplewebsite.com"
response = requests.get(url)
video_link = re.search("https.*m3u8", response.text) #http/https
print(video_link) #m3u8 link
```

- **Please read the website policy before proceeding to use the m3u8 url. If its free to use then only use the m3u8 file otherwise it can be a breach of policy.**
- More on M3U8 ->
  The M3U8 files are simple text files which contains the information of audio/video located on the internet.

See: > https://www.lifewire.com/m3u8-file-2621956

For using M3U8 file, you can use HLS.js library developed by Apple.
See: >  https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js